# Finding maximum value of a list(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my function:

```
def listMaxInd(l):
    max_val = l[0]
    maxIndex = 0
    count_assigment = 1
    count_comparison = 0
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        count_comparison=count_comparison+1
        if l[i]>max_val:
            max_val=l[i]
            maxIndex=l.index(max_val)
            count_assigment = count_assigment + 1

    return maxIndex,count_assigment,count_comparison
```

I want to find maximum value of a list by *only* assigning indices, and not by assigning the values.

In my version I *am* assigning values still. Is it possible to find the maximum without this?

Comment: I'm trying to make your question readable and to the point, sorry if we are clashing here.

Comment: I have tried to explain clearly ? Isn'n it understandable ?

Comment: I think I've captured what you want now; feel free to correct the question text if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use a loop and cannot use the `max()` function, then you are stuck with assigning at the very least the index pointing at the maximum found so far:

```
max_index = 0
for i, value in enumerate(l):
    if value > l[max_index]:
        max_index = i
```

When the loop completes, `max_index` points to the (first occurrence of) the maximum value in `l`. `enumerate()` is a more compact and efficient method of generating indices in a loop, together with the values iterated over.

The more efficient method would be to use the `max()` function with a key:

```
max_index = max(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)
```

This will return the (first) index of the maximum value in list `l`; given a list of indices (`range(len(l))`), it'll find the index for which `l.__getitem__()` returns the highest value.

Comment: I don' want to use max fuction.So i have to modify this algorithm.Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Worth noting that he'll get the _first_ index of the maximum value, not a list of the indices of occurrences of the max value (if there are duplicates)?

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Both approaches do that.

Comment: Agreed.  I just can't tell if that's intended or not - the question isn't all that clear.

Comment: My task is to modify this algorithm so that i have to use as much as possible assignments of indexes not of data

Comment: @MustafaOgünÖztürk: I figured out what you wanted, see updated answer.